# Can I create a UITableViewController that inherits from a custom subclass of UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have common functionality that I need to access from all screens of my app: a right bar button item and associated action.

So as not to repeat the code I would like to set this up in a custom UIViewController and have all my view controllers inherit from it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(lightsCamera)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
}

- (void)lightsCamera {
    …
}
```

However, I have a number of UITableViewControllers however and I would like to know if it is possible for them to inherit the functionality too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's fairly trivial to recreate you own `UITableViewController` from your custom `UIViewController` subclass.

The controller must have a `UITableView` property, which is also set to its `view` property, set the proper resizing masks, set yourself as the table's delegate and datasource, and remember to flash the scrollbar indicators in `-viewDidAppear:` and you've more or less got it.

More [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html).

Comment: Do you know if this is the only way to achieve what I'm looking for? If so I will ditch `UITableViewController` and make my own as you suggest.

Comment: Overriding methods in a Category is not a very good idea, so this will probably be your best bet. Alternatively, you could just subclass `UITableViewController` and add your functionality there, and then have the rest of your custom table controllers inherit from it.

Comment: That is precisely the answer I was looking for :) You made my day!

Comment: The only time anyone should ever use a UITableViewController is when they want to use static cells, which are only supported in UITableViewController.... I don't believe this solution gets around that fact.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not adding any new attributes to the view controller, you can implement the two methods in a category on UIViewController and all the subclasses will inherit it by default.

Comment: Do you mean a category on the view or on the view controller? Can I access the `navigationItem` of a view controller from its view?

Comment: I think he meant to say UIViewController. That's where this functionality belongs. No need to involve UIView.